# Spacer won't accept margin in css

Tags: html, css

My spacer won't use a given margin tag. I'm using bootstrap so it might interfere with my margin tag. If I give a div in between my topnav and main page content a spacer class tag with 20px margin-top it won't work. I've tried View Height instead of px as well but that won't work as well. I've also tried replacing the div in the main content container but that won't work either. Thanks in advance!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #cccaca;
}

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  
/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
  
/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
  
/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  color: #222;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.spacer-top {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.spacer-topnav {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.Spacer-Nav-To-Content {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
</header>
<body>
    <div class="spacer-top"></div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-auto">
            <h3>....</h3>
            <h4>Developer</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <!--TOPNAV-->
            <div class="topnav spacer-topnav">
                <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
                <a href="#news">CV/Resumé</a>
                <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Spacer-Nav-To-Content"></div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-auto">
            <img src="images/Profile_foto.png" alt="Profile Picture">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2><b>Hello,</b></h2>
            <h3><i>Here is a bit about me:</i></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using !important in your css code.

```
.spacer-top {margin-top: 70px !important;}
```